# Move S3 files to Cloudinary

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloudinary

I want to Close my S3 bucket and I decide to move all the images to the Cloudinary. The Total files size is around 200GB. Is Cloudinary or AWS Provide any service to move the files?

Answer (score 0):

You can upload resources from s3 by either using auto-upload mapping which will upload it lazily or simply using the upload API and uploading them in a loop.
More information here: https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/202520882-How-can-I-migrate-my-images-from-my-own-S3-account-into-Cloudinary-